# Can not see the content of Tensorflow tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
# command line argument

# plots accuracy and loss curves
def plot_model_history(model_history):
    """
    Plot Accuracy and Loss curves given the model_history
    """
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2,figsize=(15,5))
    # summarize history for accuracy
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['accuracy'])+1),model_history.history['accuracy'])
    axs[0].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_accuracy'])+1),model_history.history['val_accuracy'])
    axs[0].set_title('Model Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_ylabel('Accuracy')
    axs[0].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[0].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['accuracy'])+1),len(model_history.history['accuracy'])/10)
    axs[0].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    # summarize history for loss
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),model_history.history['loss'])
    axs[1].plot(range(1,len(model_history.history['val_loss'])+1),model_history.history['val_loss'])
    axs[1].set_title('Model Loss')
    axs[1].set_ylabel('Loss')
    axs[1].set_xlabel('Epoch')
    axs[1].set_xticks(np.arange(1,len(model_history.history['loss'])+1),len(model_history.history['loss'])/10)
    axs[1].legend(['train', 'val'], loc='best')
    fig.savefig('plot.png')
    plt.show()

# Define data generators
train_dir = 'data/train'
val_dir = 'data/test'

num_train = 28709
num_val = 7178
batch_size = 64
num_epoch = 50

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        train_dir,
        target_size=(48,48),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        val_dir,
        target_size=(48,48),
        batch_size=batch_size,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# Create the model
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))
    
model.load_weights('model.h5')
cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)
emotion_dict = {0: "Angry", 1: "Disgusted", 2: "Fearful", 3: "Happy", 4: "Neutral", 5: "Sad", 6: "Surprised"}
frame = cv2.imread('disgust.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
facecasc = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = facecasc.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y-50), (x+w, y+h+10), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
    cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray, (48, 48)), -1), 0)
    prediction = model.predict(cropped_img)
    t = model.layers[-1].output
    print(t) # I want to see the content of this tensor!
    maxindex = int(np.argmax(prediction))
```

This result output is this.

```
Tensor("dense_1/Softmax:0", shape=(None, 7), dtype=float32)
```

I've tried many ways to solve this, like using Session and enable eager execution. However both of them do not work because the former complains that the graph is empty like below.

```
RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run().
```

The latter one complains that tensor does not have a numpy attribute.

```
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
```

How can I solve this problem?

My tensorflow version is 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Using tf.print [1] should work.

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/print

With Model subclassing as mentioned in my comment.

```
class Model(tf.keras.models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize model."""
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        """Build model."""
        self.dense = Dense(10, activation='relu')
        self.projection = Dense(7, activation='softmax')

    def call(self, inputs, training, print=True):
        """Call function."""
        inputs = self.dense(inputs)
        outputs = self.projection(inputs)
        if print:
            tf.print(outputs)
        return outputs
```

Comment: It says that 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_datatype_enum'.

Comment: So from the docs you can only print printable python objects and the layer.output object is not one. Since you want the output of your softmax layer is suggest just printing the `prediction` object. If you want to insert prints of different tensors when calling your model i suggest using Model subclassing [1]. I have added a small example to my previous answer to illustrate.

[1] https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model